# fancybox 3 selector for dynamically added elements and multiple gallery

Tags: jquery, fancybox-3

In the documentation of fancybox v.3 says "Sometimes you might need to bind fancybox to dynamically added elements. Use selector...". Everything is fine, but I need to disable the automatic grouping of galleries and customize multiple gallery selector.

Default behavior:

```
$().fancybox({
    selector : '[data-fancybox]:visible'
});
```

All visible links with data-fancybox will be merged into ONE gallery.
I need to create different galleries according to the values of data-fancybox, like data-fancybox="gallery1", data-fancybox="gallery2", etc. At the same time, fancybox should continue to listen to dynamically added content.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: @Artem, i expanded the description of the question as much as possible.

Comment: Hello @MGreen What about removing the `data-fancybox` from all links and manual init of fancybox with other selector than default? :)

Comment: Hey. No, I tried, it didn't work. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a valid question, because early versions of v3 worked like you described - items were grouped by `data-fancybox` attribute. But, in the practice, that caused some confusion, because `data-fancybox` attribute adds click event by default.

But, do not be afraid to create your own trigger function, it so easy. For example, you could choose to use `data-group` attribute for grouping:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-group]', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var group = $('[data-group="' + $this.data('group') + '"]');

  $.fancybox.open(group, {
    // Put your options here, for example:
    thumbs : {
      autoStart : true
    }
  }, group.index($this));

  return false;
});
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZqBJyj?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks so much. It's nice to hear the answer from the author of the script. I came to a similar decision, but thought there was an easier way, so I asked here.

Comment: Wow, although this is an old answer. This worked for me! (V3) helpt me out a lot. Thanks!